# Wordpress doesn't answer

Tags: wordpress, plugins, server

I'm working on a client Wordpress and recently we had to migrate it from one server to another. When we did that, we couldn't access the backend, and were having error 500.

We've tried to solve this, but we can just access to it from webFTP, and all the changes we're implementing are not working. We modify the files and it looks like changes aren't being made. Also, we have "All in one Wordpress Security" installed and working, and maybe that's causing the issue. We can't deactivate the plugins, cause the web does nothing when we rename the folder.

Anyone knows why this is happening and how could I solve it?

Thanks in advance. Kind regards.

Comment: Get access to the error logs, that is always the first thing you do when you encounter a 500.

Comment: How to disable plugins by changing the corresponding database entries is easy enough to research, so maybe try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved changing one file in a plugin called "Woo Button Text", but not just that. Apparently, there are some things that our hosting service did wrong, and the files are still in the old server, that's why changing all the files didn't work.

Thanks for the replies. Kind Regards.